# binding NSInteger in sqlite statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

The following statement is throwing a warning: `Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int'`

```
sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, obj.extId);
```

Here `obj.extId` is of type NSInteger. I cannot keep it as `int` because there is a possibility that `extID` may contain very long digits.

How do I remove this warning? What casting do I need to do? Instead of `sqlite3_bind_int`, can I user `sqlite3_bind_int64` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast it to `int`:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, (int)obj.extId);
```

or use the `int64` bind function:

```
sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 1, obj.extId);
```

The issue is that if you build for both 32- and 64-bit then the size of `NSInteger` will change depending on what you are building.  I think the first approach is best if you know the integer won't go beyond 32-bits and if you know it can go beyond 32-bits then use `int64_t` instead of `NSInteger` and use the second approach.

Comment: typecasting it to int may lead to data loss.!! I don't what that to happen..!

Comment: @Shradha OK updated my answer.  I think using `int64_t` is best if you think the value will go beyond 32-bits.

Comment: The problem is that the integer may go beyond 32 bits, so i cannot typecast it as int.

Comment: I am building for both 32-bit and 64 bit :(

Comment: Then don't use `NSInteger` at all; as my answer states use `int64_t` if you want more than 32-bits.

Comment: If you are expecting your integer to possibly be longer than 32 bits, you can't use `NSInteger`. Explicitly use `int64_t`; it doesn't require that you build for only 64-bit machines.

Comment: @IanMacDonald: are you suggesting that I declare all my NSInteger type variables as int64_t ?

Comment: I am suggesting that any `NSInteger` that you are expecting to be larger than 32 bits should be `int64_t`.

Comment: I am also suggesting it in my answer and twice now in comments in this answer.